# Scrapy SitemapSpider not continuing after clean shutdown

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running a scrapy sitemap spider using JOBSDIR using the documentation here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html.

However, I will do a clean shutdown, ctrl + c (I have double checked multiple times this is a clean shutdown and I am not sending ctrl+c twice), and the spider will be unable to continue. The output will say "Filtered duplicate request: example.com/sitemap.xml"
but there will still be loads of unseen requests and a very large requests.queue file in the JOBSDIR folder.

Why is scrapy filtering out the starting point sitemap instead of picking up with requests.queue? Obviously if it filters out the only url I provide it, the sitemap, it will never get anywhere. Any ideas?

EDIT: One thing I'm doing is starting my spider from a python script, not from the scrapy command line. In doing so, perhaps I am not passing the -s argument scrapy recommends. What does the "-s" do? Where is documentation for this varaible?

```
    process = CrawlerProcess({'JOBDIR': '.jobs/alexa_site_' + str(alexa_site_id)})

    MySpider.set_settings(alexa_site)
    MySpider.custom_settings[
        'USER_AGENT'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36"

    process.crawl(MySpider, alexa_site_id=alexa_site_id)
    process.start()
```

Here is the spider code:

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    custom_settings = {
        'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True,
        'MEMUSAGE_ENABLED': True,
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 20,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 100000,
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'CRITICAL',
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
            'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
        },
        'ROTATING_PROXY_BAN_POLICY': 'spiders.classes.proxies.policy.MyPolicy',
        'ROTATING_PROXY_PAGE_RETRY_TIMES': 20,
        'ROTATING_PROXY_LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 5,
        'ROTATING_PROXY_CLOSE_SPIDER': True,
        'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 502, 503, 504, 522, 524, 408, 403],
        'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1,
        'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue',
        'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue',
        'TELNETCONSOLE_USERNAME': 'scrapy',
        'TELNETCONSOLE_PASSWORD': 'scrapy',
        'DUPEFILTER_DEBUG': True
    }

    name = None
    allowed_domains = []
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
        le = LinkExtractor()
        links = le.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link.ur, self.parse)
```

Comment: `-s` is just used to override a setting value. Why are you overriding the settings on `MySpider` and not passing it into `CrawlerProcess`?

Comment: I don't follow, what am I overriding? Isn't this line passing it?

`process = CrawlerProcess({'JOBDIR': '.jobs/alexa_site_' + str(alexa_site_id)})`

Comment: That line passes in a single setting, not all the settings. I am not sure if it is related to your problem, but usually you would pass in all the settings to `CrawlerProcess` and not with `set_settings`. What is in `alexa_site`?

Comment: Just a unique_number. Okay, so I should pass all the settings via CrawlerProcess, not on the spider, that makes sense.

I still don't understand why scrapy is filtering out the sitemap. The JOBSDIR requests.queue file is HUGE, why isn't scrapy using those to start?

Comment: Does `alexa_site` contain only a unique number? (I'm not referring to `alexa_site_id`.)

Comment: Also, can you show your spider code?

Comment: Added in code. alexa_site is unique to a spider. So in this case, alexa_site_id = 21095, and alexa_site is just a Django objects with a id field. For this example, alexa_site_id never changes, even  between starting and stopping scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190027/discussion-between-superdee-and-malberts).